# Simple React Element not working, How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The so called button element does not display

HTML Code

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

  <div id="TestButtonContainer"></div>

  <script module="TestButton.js"></script>
```

Testbutton.js

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#TestButtonContainer');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(e(TestButton));
```

Comment: I think you meant `<script src="TestButton.js" type="module"></script>`

Comment: Now I get You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".

Answer (score 0):

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#TestButtonContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(TestButton), domContainer);
```